# Android: execute method after returning to main activity from intent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have seen many examples with

```
startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
```

and then using

```
onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)
```

but for me I dont need to pass anything, I simply want to startActivity(intent), and when intent activity returns, a method get called in main activity..
Any tutorial on doing this?

EDIT:
Here a sample code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_options);

    createEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createEvent);
    createEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(optionsInterface.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

here, after I return from MainActivity (press back, or just close it), I want the activity to perform a task ( with no data being passed from MainActivity)

Comment: Could you explain more...

Comment: I have added sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use startactivityforResult().. it doesn't matter if you send any data back or not... when you use startactivityonResult() the method onActivityResult will get called...just check for the request code there and do whatever you want...sending back something is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `startActivity()` you might want to use [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), so that you get a call back on result.